# How to hide part of the ip address and/or host name using `preg_replace()`?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to make these strings
`192.168.0.1` and `some.subdomain.domain.com`
become 
`192.168.0.***` and `***.subdomain.domain.com`
with `preg_replace()` function **in one sentence**.

Is it possibe?

I've tried 
`preg_replace('/([0123456789]$)|(^(.)[a-z][^\.])/','***',$a)`
with `$a` as `some.subdomain.domain.com` and `192.168.0.1`
but it seems like something wrong with my pattern.

(Optionally): and is it possible to mask these parts with asterisks as exact number of masked letters/numbers, e.g. `127.0.0.1 -> ***.0.0.1`, `10.4.8.2 -> **.4.8.2`, and `sub.domain.com - > ***.domain.com`, `s.domain.com -> *.domain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, `preg_replace` can use an array as first parameter. So you could try something like this (cannot test at the moment):

```
$patterns = [
    '/^[a-z]+/i',
    '/[0-9]+$/'
];
$newHost = preg_replace($patterns, '***', $host);
```

For the second question I would try something like this (not tested yet too):

```
$patterns = [
    '/^([a-z]*)([a-z])([a-z]*)/i',
    '/([0-9]*)([0-9])([0-9]*)$/'
];
$newHost = preg_replace($patterns, '\1*\3', $host);
```

I would test tomorrow if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

well `preg_replace()` is a little bit slow there are better ways to do it like `explode()` if you want to hide the last part of the ip do something like:

```
<?php



$ip = "192.168.0.1";

$ip_items = explode('.', $ip);

$filtered_ip = ''; //The var to store the filtered ip

foreach($ip_items as $item) {
  if($item == end($ip_items)) { //check if its the last part of the IP
    $ip_part = '***';
  } else {
    $ip_part = $item . '.';
  }

$filtered_ip .= $ip_part;

}

echo $filtered_ip;



?>
```

result: `192.168.0.***`

and if you want to filter other parts of the ip like the first one use `$ip_items[0]` instead of `end($ip_items)`

example :

```
<?php



$ip = "192.168.0.1";

$ip_items = explode('.', $ip);

$filtered_ip = ''; //The var to store the filtered ip

foreach($ip_items as $item) {
  if($item == $ip_items[0]) { //check if its the first part of the IP
    $ip_part = '***.'; //we added the '.' to that one because its the first item
  } else {
    $ip_part = $item . '.';
  }

$filtered_ip .= $ip_part;

}

echo $filtered_ip;



?>
```

result: `***.168.0.1.`

**EDIT:** and for the second question you can use `str_length` to get the length and use `str_repeat` to repeat the character

example:

```
<?php



$ip = "192.168.0.1";

$ip_items = explode('.', $ip);

$filtered_ip = ''; //The var to store the filtered ip

foreach($ip_items as $item) {
  if($item == end($ip_items)) { //check if its the last part of the IP
    $ip_part = str_repeat("*", strlen($item)) ;
  } else {
    $ip_part = $item . '.';
  }

$filtered_ip .= $ip_part;

}

echo $filtered_ip;



?>
```